# MySQL multi delete operator does not delete anything

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

query below does not delete anything, though there is 3 records to delete in table flight:

```
delete p, f
from passgr p STRAIGHT_JOIN  flight f on p.flight_id=f.flight_id
where f.cityfrom_id=1;
```

The command does not delete record(s) from `passgr` or `flight`.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Must work. https://dbfiddle.uk/P0aSa9jh The only thing which may interfere is FOREIGN KEY restrictions, both between these tables and with third table. Does some error message is produced?

Comment: FLIGHT is master table, PASSGR - detail table, besides, passgr is a detail table for table SEAT. No other links present. 
No error messages. Message "no records deleted"

Comment: What is the reason in STRAIGHT_JOIN? Does the rows are not deleted with common INNER JOIN? Show **complete** tables definitions. *Message "no records deleted"* This is NOT error message produced by MySQL. Obtain MySQL diagnostic.

Comment: 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0004 seconds.)

Comment: I tried both INNER JOIN and STRAIGHT_JOIN. STRAIGHT JOIN I took from some post on stackoverflow. It for deleting from tables in order their names are written. Works only for InnoDB.

Comment: 'Works only for InnoDB' - what's your point? are the tables not innodb?

Comment: MyISAM tables. It seems that misunderstood my post. I meant that STRAIGHT_JOIN  only works for InnoDB

Comment: DELETE operator still deletes nothing:
please, look at https://dbfiddle.uk/5Rd4Y2hU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much seems that something in your criteria fails to fulfill. You either do not find a proper pair of `passgr` and `flight` sharing the same `flight_id` as your `ON` condition expects, or there is no `flight` whose `cityfrom_id` is 1.

Reproducible example:

```
create table passgr(passgr_id int primary key auto_increment, flight_id int);
create table flight(flight_id int primary key auto_increment, cityfrom_id int);

insert into flight(cityfrom_id) values(1);
insert into passgr(flight_id)
select flight_id
from flight;

select * from flight;

select * from passgr;

delete p, f
from passgr p JOIN  flight f on p.flight_id=f.flight_id
where f.cityfrom_id=1;

select * from flight;

select * from passgr;
```

[image]

And it works with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` as well:

[image]

EDIT

In the comment-section this fiddle was mentioned: https://dbfiddle.uk/5Rd4Y2hU

[image]

along with the question as of why is this not removing the records. In order to understand that, let's look at the facts:

- `flight.flight_id` is an auto-incremented `primary key`, starting from 30
- when `flight` records are created, `flight_id` is unspecified and since two such records are created, we will end up with a record whose `flight_id` is 30 and another, whose flight_id is 31
- when records are inserted into `passgr`, their `flight_id` is specified as 1 and 2, respectively
- the removal of records has a `join` condition according to which `flight_id` of `p` and `f` pairs should match
- but there is no such pair in `passgr` and `flight`, whose `flight_id` would match, because 1 differs from both 30 and 31 and 2 differs from both 30 and 31

As a result, nothing is deleted:

[image]

But, if the `auto_increment` starts from 1 (instead of 30), then the `flight_id` values of `flight` will be 1 and 2, respectively and, as a result, a record will be removed from `flight` and another from `passgr`, consistently with your expectations:

[image]

Comment: Yes, your example works. But question was why my text mentioned on dbfiddle.uk/5Rd4Y2hU does not work?

Comment: @Mike I have edited my answer, explaining the reason of the behavior you have experienced during your tests.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, i did not do it on time